# How do I get an input's `checked` state in Vue 3 with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using Vue 3 and TS 4.4. I'm trying to get a checkbox value without having to do this: `(event.target as any).checked`. Is this possible in Vue? What's the right way to do this?

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
function doThing(checked: boolean) {
  console.log("Do thing", checked);
}
</script>

<template>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    @change="(event) => doThing((event.target as any).checked)"
  />
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (i.e., using the `as` keyword) is unavoidable here, but you *can* replace `any` with the actual type of the event target ([`HTMLInputElement`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9d443b7/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L7016) in this case) to access the `checked` property.

```html
<template>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    @change="(event) => doThing((event.target as HTMLInputElement).checked)"
  />
</template>
```